#enable-portals Tag Missing in Chrome?
My question is pretty straightforward: what happened to the enable portals flag in Chrome? Tried both Chrome and Chrome Canary (latest version of each) and couldn't find the tag, despite it being referenced by the official Chromium Docs. Did it get replaced? Did it get removed?


The flag was removed as "expired" for Chromium 110 last year.

commit 51dbb66f37b47b9bb24ea54c2c29f40f06cf0755
Date:   Wed Mar 15 15:04:27 2023 +0000

    Remove enable-portals and enable-portals-cross-origin flags.

    Fixed: 1419226,1419227
    Change-Id: Ied9b5c845b6cd97b589facabb4dae95c00eed0a0
    Reviewed-on: https://chromium-review.googlesource.com/c/chromium/src/+/4338519
    Cr-Commit-Position: refs/heads/main@{#1117529}


Thanks! Too bad such a cool experimental feature is going in the trash pile
